# Jacobian of $R^{-1} v$ with respect to $R \in SO(3)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations, quaternions, lie-derivative

According to "A micro Lie theory for state estimation in robotics", the Jacobian $J_R^{R\cdot{}\mathbf{v}} = -\mathbf{R}[\mathbf{v}]_\times$. Here non-bolded R is an element of SO(3) *or* an element of the pure quaternions $\mathbb{H}_p$ acting on a vector $\mathbf{v}$, and bold $\mathbf{R}$ is the corresponding rotation matrix. $[\cdot]_\times$ is the skew-symmetric matrix, i.e., $[\mathbf{a}]_\times{}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}\times{}\mathbf{b}.$

I want to find $J_R^{ {R}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{v}}$, and according to the same paper, it seems as simple as $$J_R^{ {R}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{v}} = J_{R^{-1}}^{ {R}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{v}} J_R^{R^{-1}} = (-\mathbf{R}^{-1}[\mathbf{v}]_\times)(-\mathbf{R}) = \mathbf{R}^T[\mathbf{v}]_\times \mathbf{R}.$$

I get the same result if I do the limit by hand, as shown in eq. (123) in the referenced paper below.

However, this seems wrong. I am checking derivations in some source code, and it seems they have used $$ J_R^{ {R}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{v}} = [\mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{v}]_\times $$ which just seems impossible. What is going on?

A micro Lie theory for state estimation in robotics:
http://www.iri.upc.edu/files/scidoc/2089-A-micro-Lie-theory-for-state-estimation-in-robotics.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean by "pure quaternion", but the quaternion $R$ is not pure imaginary; $R = \cos\theta/2 + (\sin\theta/2)n$ where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation and $n$ is the unit normal of the plane of rotation expressed as an imaginary quaternion. Then $R\cdot v = Rv\bar R$ where $\bar R$ is the conjugate, and $R\bar R = \bar RR = 1$.

As for your question, they are equivalent expressions. Consider a vector $w$ and let $v, w$ be represented by imaginary quaternions. Then
$$
  \mathbf R^T[v]_\times\mathbf Rw
    = \bar R(v\times(Rw\bar R))R
    = (\bar RvR)\times(\bar RRw\bar RR)
    = (\bar RvR)\times w
    = [\mathbf R^Tv]_\times w,
$$
so $\mathbf R^T[v]_\times\mathbf R = [\mathbf R^Tv]_\times$.

Comment: You're of course right, it's supposed to be unitary quaternions.

Comment: Could this actually be shown more succinctly by restricting yourself to rotation matrices, and saying $R^T[v]_\times Rw = R^T (v \times Rw) = R^T v \times R^T R w = R^T v \times w = [R^T v]_\times$?

Comment: And does this imply that $A [x]_\times B = [Ax]_\times AB$ in general?

Comment: @lericson You're right about using rotation matrices, I just don't usually think in those terms; either way the essence is the geometric argument that rotations preserve the cross product. And that's why I don't think your general formula works (unless I'm misunderstanding how you're getting that) because $A(v\times w) \ne Av\times Aw$ iff A is a rotation (or zero).

Answer (score 1):

The expressions $\mathbf{R}[\mathbf{v}]_{\times}\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ and $[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v}]_\times$ are equivalent.

The map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathfrak{so}(3)$; $f(\mathbf{v})=[\mathbf{v}]_{\times}$ is an isomorphism of Lie algebra representations from the standard representation to the adjoint representation,
$$\mathrm{ad}_X(f(\mathbf{v}))=f(X\mathbf{v})\tag{$\ast$}$$
for all $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $X\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$.
Writing $\mathbf{R}=e^X$ and using $\mathrm{Ad}_{(e^X)}=e^{(\mathrm{ad}_X)}$ and $(\ast)$ we have
$$
\mathbf{R}[\mathbf{v}]_{\times}\mathbf{R}^{-1}
=\mathrm{Ad}_{(e^X)}f(\mathbf{v})
=e^{(\mathrm{ad}_X)}f(\mathbf{v})
=f(e^X\mathbf{v})
=[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v}]_\times
.$$